# jQuery draggable area

Tags: jquery, draggable

EDIT: Browser issue, not resolved.

I'm working on building a form inside a modal, on one tab there's a dropdown list with checkboxes. If one of the checkboxes are checked, two drag & drop divs appends from the database with all code ready. My problem is that the draggable area is not restricted on the right, so the div can be dragged without limit to the side.
I found an example of the [same problem](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) that i have on the jQuery draggable guide.

This is the information i found on the API:

```
$(".selector").draggable({
   containment: "parent"
});
```

But neither "parent", "document" or "window" solves it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why your code doesn't work but here is another way you can achieve this. wrap your draggable element

```
$('.selector')
```

with a parent HTML element. than do something like this:

```
<div id="drag-container">
 <div class="selector"></div>
</div>


$(".selector").draggable({
   containment: "#drag-container"
});
```

**Edit**

@Habib suggestion made me relize.

your draggable element's width should be set to a smaller width than the parent.
see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gababa/nfck90db/5/) , i believe that was your problem.

Comment: Tried that, wrapping it doesn't change anything. I'm concerned there's not a solution to my problem since the official jQuery website has the same problem.

Comment: see the example, its not leaving parent container
https://jsfiddle.net/bktgoyjs/1/

Comment: @kifka I didn't realise it might be a browse issue, thank you!

Comment: @kifka Both works equal to me in your fiddle. The width is already smaller in my code :)